# What are pros/cons of cron job over an infinite loop running?

Tags: ruby, cron

We coded a scheduled job in an infinite loop with a 120 second sleep. The scheduled task is a ping on a website to get a tiny bit of data. What are the advantages/disadvantages of using a cron job over our solution?

Comment: A better source for an answer would be http://superuser.com. This question is one that sysadmins deal with often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Advantages of a `cron` job:

- You more easily have control over when it runs. You control the minute, hour, day, etc, that it will execute
- It's easier to write the code and to manage its operation. It eliminates the looping and timing logic in the task, and you run `crontab` to change the timing or shut it off.
- It's not occupying memory in your system when it's not running.
- If it fails and exits for some reason, it will start up again when the proper time comes

Advantages of the infinite loop:

- It doesn't have the overhead of being restarted every time it's needed

I think the pros/cons regarding CPU real time and memory are probably slight in this specific case. But I prefer a `cron` job for anything that's going to run for an indefinite period of time because of the control over when it executes and ease of administration.

Comment: One of the biggest advantages to using a cron job is the ease of writing the code and setting it up to run. It's nothing different than a normal command-line utility that is fired-off periodically by the system. No `chkconfig` scripts need to be set up, no init.d, just a crontab entry.

Comment: @theTinMan indeed, my comment on "easier to manage" was about ease of setting it up to run and code it. I wasn't very clear on that.

Answer (score 4):

Building a program that polls a remote site offers these problems/benefits,

- A defect (unhandled exception) and the program could fail, and stop polling
- A delay in the program could lead to time slipping (>120s delay)
- Separation of concerns - the scheduling of the polling mixed with program logic makes for more code (and more chances to fail)
- DRY - why (re)build cron functionality when it already exists
- Program must sit in memory even when it is not being used (1/120s)

Cron is built for periodic scheduling, here are some problems/benefits,

- Cron already built, and works, very reliable
- providing environment and logging output require care
- Child program must be restarted every 120s
- Cron does not check for other programs/servers/dependencies
- Cron does not signal/start downstream dependencies
- Cron does not offer tight scheduling constraints (neither sub-second, nor near-real-time)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answers above there is one more caveat. You're lucky because your schedule is 120 seconds so you can actually specify it in any of the known cron expression parsers (equals 2 minutes interval).

If it was say 125 you would not be able to specify it in any dialect.

Say you wanted a 45 seconds interval. In some dialects of cron expressions (ex. Quartz) you can specify seconds. The caveat here is that it's still not possible to specify 45 seconds intervals.

Consider the cron expression 0/13 0/7 * * * (https://crontab.guru/#0/13_0/7_*_*_*).

Crontab Guru provides the explanation for this expression as "At every 13th minute from 0 through 59 past every 7th hour from 0 through 23."

If you consult https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html (based on Quartz) and consider the expression "0/45 * */7 ? * *", then the description of the expression given is "Every 45 seconds starting at second 00, every minute, every 7 hours starting at 00am, of every day".

The calculated execution sequence is (from now):

Wed Mar 06 14:00:00 UTC 2019
Wed Mar 06 14:00:45 UTC 2019
Wed Mar 06 14:01:00 UTC 2019
Wed Mar 06 14:01:45 UTC 2019
Wed Mar 06 14:02:00 UTC 2019
Wed Mar 06 14:02:45 UTC 2019
Wed Mar 06 14:03:00 UTC 2019
Wed Mar 06 14:03:45 UTC 2019

This means that every time you overflow a bigger/time container/ you will have arrhytmia. Just so you know ;-)

PS Also worth noting that the 7 on the expression is redundant. We are restarting our rythm every minute so that implies every hour as well. CRON expressions are fun :-)